# access denied when saving xdocument

Tags: c#, iis

I'm using IIS and VS 2013. I'm creating a XDocument and wan't to save it into a local folder.

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument();
doc.Save(@"C:\temp");
```

This gives me "access denied on C:\temp". I've also tried with c\users\firstname.lastname but the result is the same.

I've tried giving everyone full control on both folders. Also tried giving my AppPool full control (shouldn't matter when everyone still has it?).

Does anyone have some tips?

Comment: Try running VS as administrator.

Comment: Have a look at [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/questions/378933/getting-http-401-3-error-despite-giving-the-application-pool-identity-permission) and [icacls](http://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html). did you pass the file name in doc.save or are you trying to overwrite the folder named temp?

Comment: Do you have modify privileges on that folder? Is the file open/being used by another process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not set a [file name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345830(v=vs.110).aspx) according to your question

```
doc.Save(@"C:\temp");
```

Should have the path and file name. It's worth checking if the [file exists first](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
string fileName = @"C:\temp\MyNewFile.xml";
if (!File.Exists(fileName))
{
    doc.Save(fileName);
}
```